# Canon iR2018 armbian drivers on CUPS

Tags: linux, drivers, printing, network-printer, cups

I have Canon iR2018 printer and I am trying to set it as network printer using CUPS (it already has some network capabilities, but it does not work for macs and other devices).

I plugged the printer into OrangePi One, which serves as my home server, via usb. OrangePi has armbian installed (message with "Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) with Linux 5.9.14-sunxi" pops up when I connect via ssh).

OrangePi has CUPS installed via aptitude, version after `apt list -a CUPS` is

```
cups/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 armhf [installed]
```

[I have access to web interface, where I am able to add printer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYYfM.png) 
The CUPS correctly sees the iR2018 but when selected, there were no canon drivers.

For lack of drivers, I downloaded [UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux V5.20](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/products/imagerunner/ir2018.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit))
 (which is oficial cannon website, and detail of the printer I am looking for), and run the **install.sh** script, which was included in drivers package. It worked, in a way.

In the CUPS, there are now many new Canon printer drivers.

```
Canon i-SENSYS X 1643P UFR II (en)
Canon iPR C710/810/910 UFR II (en)
Canon iR C3120 (en)
Canon iR C3120L (en)
Canon iR C3125 (en)
Canon iR-ADV 527 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV 617 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV 717 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV 4725/4735 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV 4745/4751 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV 6000i UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV 6755/6765 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV 6780 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV 8705 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV 8786/8795 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV C257/357 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV C477 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV C3720 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV C3725/3730 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV C5735/5740 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV C5750/5760 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV C7765 UFR II (en)
Canon iR-ADV C7780/7770 UFR II (en)
Canon iR2425 UFR II (en)
Canon iR2625/2630 UFR II (en)
Canon iR2635/2645 UFR II (en)
Canon LBP222 UFR II (en)
Canon LBP223 UFR II (en)
Canon LBP225 UFR II (en)
Canon LBP226 UFR II (en)
Canon LBP227 UFR II (en)
Canon LBP228 UFR II (en)
Canon LBP1127C / C1127P UFR II (en)
Canon LBP1238 / 1238P/Pr UFR II (en)
Canon MF1127C / C1127iF/i UFRII (en)
Canon MF1238 / 1238iF/i UFR II (en)
```

BUT! There is no iR2018, I tried to pick `Canon iR2425 UFR II (en)` which seemed to be the closest choice (by name). But It did not work (I was unable to send document to print from my Macbook pro).

I also tried to install `UFRII/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux v3.10` but the script ends up with message, that the drivers are already there.

**My questions are:**

- How can I get rid of the drivers I installed first?
- Is there a driver specifically for iR2018 or is it hidden under some
  codename in my already installed drivers?
- Is there something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you receive error messages of any kind when installing either driver package?

Comment: No, I did not :-(.